# Strange problem is occurring in node js (swapping request)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, routes

I have created a web application using node js (express) and MySQL. It is an ERP solution.

A problem is occurring while saving sales.

When 2 requests are sent to the server at the same time from 2 different system one of them is getting the correct response and the other one is receiving the response similar to the 1st one.

Suppose 2 persons saving sale at the same time. 1st person's sales id is 10 and 2nd one's sales id is 11.

In response, 1st person is getting an invoice of invoice 10, but the 2nd one is getting invoice details of 10 while he/she should get invoice details of 11.

What would be the possible reason for this issue?

My sales process is as follows:

1. When a user saves the sales it returns a **sales id**.
2. Through that **sales id** again a request is made to get the details of that sale.

There is no problem with saving the data.

But when I get the sales details it messes up.

**Here is the sales route:**

```
router.route('sales/:id')
    .get(async function (req, res, next) {
        let json = {};
        let report = new ReportObj(req.conn);
        let dbs_name = req.session.main_db;

        try {
            json = await report.getSalesById({
                dbs_name,
                ids: req.params.id
            });
            res.send(json);
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    });
```

and **this is the getSalesById function:**

```
this.getSalesById = function (sendData) {
    // console.log(sendData);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        json = {};
        var select_header_with_date_sql = `SELECT
            ...
        FROM sales_entry_header seh
            LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = seh.customer_id
            LEFT JOIN form_type ft On ft.id = c.form_type
            LEFT JOIN state_list s ON s.id = c.state
            LEFT JOIN \`${sendData.dbs_name}\`.users u ON u.id = seh.user_sold
        WHERE seh.id = ?`;
        conn.query(select_header_with_date_sql, [sendData.ids], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                resolve({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'Error',
                    debug: err
                });
            } else {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    json = result[0];
                    var details_sql = `SELECT
                        ...
                    FROM sales_entry_details sed
                        LEFT JOIN products p ON p.\`product-id\` = sed.product_id 
                        LEFT JOIN hsn h ON h.id = p.hsn
                        LEFT JOIN unit_type u ON u.id = p.\`unit-type\`
                        LEFT JOIN purchase_entry_details ped ON ped.id = sed.batch_no
                        LEFT JOIN salesman sm ON sm.id = sed.salesman
                    WHERE sed.sales_entry_header_id = ?`;
                    conn.query(details_sql, [json.sales_id], function (err, details_result) {
                        if (err) {
                            resolve({
                                status: 'error',
                                message: 'Error',
                                debug: err
                            });
                        } else {
                            json.items = details_result.map(function (obj) {
                                obj.available_qty = obj.unit_purchase - obj.unit_sale + +obj.unit_sale_return - obj.unit_purchase_return + +obj.qty;
                                obj.return_available_qty = obj.unit_sale - obj.unit_sale_return;
                                return obj;
                            });
                            resolve(json);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        status: "error",
                        message: "No sales selected"
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Please add some code or fiddle.

Comment: @AbhishekMani I have added code as you asked!

Comment: Please add your save function as well?

Comment: Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example. Check this link for help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: how do you create the connection to your database? do you reuse the existing connection, or do you use connection pooling?

Comment: I used connection pooling

Comment: what is conn then? the pool or an allocated connection? can you show that part of your code as well?

Comment: I think the problem is with variable declaration! when I am declaring `json = {};` in `getSalesById` without `var` that is being declared as global var. That might be the problem. I changed with `var json = {};` the problem is not occurring so far. Thanks, for trying to help I appreciate your effort :).

Answer (score 1):

There are few assumption. But I am not sure.
Did try to write ‘console.log’ after both function beginning and before ‘resolve()’.

Check out request params, and results. Pay your attention for
- do you really handle 2 requests with different params
- do you really receive 2 requests (perhaps there is 1 request handled and you have some kind of caching)
- do you really make requests to DB with different ids.
- does DB really returns equal/unequal results

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with variable declaration!

When I am declaring `json = {};` in getSalesById without `var that is being declared as global var.

That might be the problem. I changed with `var json = {};` the problem is not occurring so far.

---

Thanks, for trying to help I appreciate your effort :).